# MvxBind CheckedChange SwitchCompat

Tags: android, xamarin, data-binding, bind, mvvmcross

I'm having troubles withing binding my `Android.Support.V7.Widget.SwitchCompat` to my viewmodel (Mvvmcross is the framework i'm using)
I did exactly the same as with the click bind on another object which works perfectly fine.

The error i'm getting when viewing the view is as following:

```
12-21 10:32:06.459 I/MvxBind (22969):  42,82 Failed to create target binding for binding CheckedChange for OnCheckedChanged
[0:] MvxBind:Warning: 42,82 Failed to create target binding for binding CheckedChange for OnCheckedChanged
```

Multiple times for the amount of switches i have.

They said it might have to do something with the linker not including stuff because of reflection magic.

This way they said you have to create a file "LinkerPleaseInclude" to keep a reference to your switchcompat. I did so as following, but still the error persists.

LinkerPleaseInclude

```
class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(TextView text)
    {
        text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
        text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
    }

    public void Include(CompoundButton cb)
    {
        cb.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
        cb.Hint = "" + cb.Hint;
    }
    public void Include(SwitchCompat cb)
    {
        cb.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
        cb.Hint = "" + cb.Hint;
    }
    public void Include(ICommand command)
    {
        command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, e) => { if (command.CanExecute(null)) command.Execute(null); };
    }
    public void Include(CheckBox checkBox)
    {
        checkBox.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
    }
}
```

My ViewLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/md_list_single_line_item_height"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/md_list_item_horizontal_edges_padding"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/md_list_item_horizontal_edges_padding">
  <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    local:MvxBind="Checked IsActive; Click OnSwitchClick; CheckedChange OnCheckedChanged" />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="@color/md_text_dark_primary_87"
    android:textSize="@dimen/md_list_item_primary_text"
    local:MvxBind="Text Name"/>
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Kind"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="@color/md_text_dark_secondary_54"
    android:textSize="@dimen/md_list_item_secondary_text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
    local:MvxBind="Text Kind"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this layout is a child of another layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="@dimen/md_list_two_line_item_height"
  android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <MvxClickableLinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/animalSelectionsList"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:divider="@drawable/divider_horizontal"
      android:showDividers="middle"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SelectionsList"
      local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_animal_selections" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Iam not sure, but maybe because android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat has nothing to do with a checkbox? And it just doesnt support CheckedChange? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html

Comment: SwitchCompat is a derived type from CompoundButton. Just as Checkbox is. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html

CompoundButton has an event `CheckedChange`

Comment: Could only ask then to look at your model. For the linker stuff, try setting the android options in your project settings differently, so that your linker does the linking for the sdk and user assemblies or none (not sure what is the default setting there atm). Just to test if it is the linkers fault.

Comment: @Cyriac I've uploaded my viewmodel to pastebin as it's a pretty big model and else i'd get the "Your question contains more code than details" error http://pastebin.com/JxGdcF0D NOTE this is the inner viewmodel (within the list) If needs be i can upload the parent viewmodel aswell. The Setting is set to None

Comment: I recreated it in my project and it doesnt work for me aswell. So either you wait till i can take a look at it tomorrow again or you ask on their github, where you will high likely get a quicker answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CheckedChange` is an event, hence it is not a public property. You cannot bind events in MvvmCross directly, unless you create your own Target Binding that handles this and exposes a Command.

This could look something like:

```
public class MvxCompoundButtonCheckedChangeBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private ICommand _command;
    private IDisposable _checkedChangeSubscription;
    private IDisposable _canExecuteSubscription;
    private readonly EventHandler<EventArgs> _canExecuteEventHandler;

    protected CompoundButton View => (CompoundButton)Target;

    public MvxCompoundButtonCheckedChangeBinding(CompoundButton view)
        : base(view)
    {
        _canExecuteEventHandler = OnCanExecuteChanged;
        _checkedChangeSubscription = view.WeakSubscribe<CompoundButton, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs>(nameof(view.CheckedChange), ViewOnCheckedChangeClick);
    }

    private void ViewOnCheckedChangeClick(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_command == null)
            return;

        if (!_command.CanExecute(null))
            return;

        _command.Execute(view.Checked);
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        _canExecuteSubscription?.Dispose();
        _canExecuteSubscription = null;

        _command = value as ICommand;
        if (_command != null)
        {
            _canExecuteSubscription = _command.WeakSubscribe(_canExecuteEventHandler);
        }
        RefreshEnabledState();
    }

    private void RefreshEnabledState()
    {
        var view = View;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        var shouldBeEnabled = false;
        if (_command != null)
        {
            shouldBeEnabled = _command.CanExecute(null);
        }
        view.Enabled = shouldBeEnabled;
    }

    private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshEnabledState();
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    public override Type TargetType => typeof(ICommand);

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            _checkedChangeSubscription?.Dispose();
            _checkedChangeSubscription = null;

            _canExecuteSubscription?.Dispose();
            _canExecuteSubscription = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

Then you need to register it in your Setup.cs in a `FillTargetFactories` override:

```
registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<View>("MyCheckedChange", 
    view => new MvxCompoundButtonCheckedChangeBinding(view));
```

Then you can bind MyCheckedChange to your command.

Comment: For what is then this class https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Binding/Droid/Target/MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding.cs ?

Comment: This works as suspected! But As @Cyriac mentioned for what is the other class?

Comment: That one is for the "Checked" source, which you are already using.

Comment: Sorry not source but target.

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced CompoundButton with SwitchCompat only, so it works now  (and renamed class):

```
public class MvxButtonCheckedChangeBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private ICommand _command;
    private IDisposable _checkedChangeSubscription;
    private IDisposable _canExecuteSubscription;
    private readonly EventHandler<EventArgs> _canExecuteEventHandler;

    public static string Name = "MyCheckedChange";

    protected CompoundButton View => (SwitchCompat)Target;

    public MvxButtonCheckedChangeBinding(SwitchCompat view)
        : base(view)
    {
        _canExecuteEventHandler = OnCanExecuteChanged;
        _checkedChangeSubscription = view.WeakSubscribe<SwitchCompat, SwitchCompat.CheckedChangeEventArgs>(nameof(view.CheckedChange), ViewOnCheckedChangeClick);
    }

    private void ViewOnCheckedChangeClick(object sender, SwitchCompat.CheckedChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        var view = (SwitchCompat)sender;

        if (view == null || _command == null)
            return;

        if (!_command.CanExecute(null))
            return;

        _command.Execute(view.Checked);
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
        _canExecuteSubscription?.Dispose();
        _canExecuteSubscription = null;

        _command = value as ICommand;
        if (_command != null)
        {
            _canExecuteSubscription = _command.WeakSubscribe(_canExecuteEventHandler);
        }
        RefreshEnabledState();
    }

    private void RefreshEnabledState()
    {
        var view = View;
        if (view == null)
            return;

        var shouldBeEnabled = false;
        if (_command != null)
        {
            shouldBeEnabled = _command.CanExecute(null);
        }
        view.Enabled = shouldBeEnabled;
    }

    private void OnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshEnabledState();
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode => MvxBindingMode.OneWay;

    public override Type TargetType => typeof(ICommand);

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            _checkedChangeSubscription?.Dispose();
            _checkedChangeSubscription = null;

            _canExecuteSubscription?.Dispose();
            _canExecuteSubscription = null;
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

Of course don't forget to register it in setup class as Cheesebaron wrote above